# Time and place scope for the new EU law (proposal) that limits border closures

Tags: european-union, borders, legislation, european-parliament

Sometime [in September](https://www.politico.eu/article/eu-judges-slam-france-migrant-pushback/)

> the European Parliament’s home affairs committee on Wednesday [Sep 20] backed legislation that allows EU countries to enact border controls only when faced with emergencies such as health or terrorism threats, and only for a limited time period.

Does that refer just to the internal or also external borders? And does the proposal (which I'm not sure if it passed the floor in the meantime) say how limited is 'limited' in some concrete terms?